# adjective denoting the turn of the century?

Tags: vocabulary

I am looking for an adjective that is related to 'turn of the century' or something like that. It seems to start with the letter 'c'. Do you know what it is

I'd appreicate your help.

Comment: Can you suggest a sentence where this adjective could be used?

Comment: Are you looking for *centennial*?

Comment: Are you sure this word exists? Do you remember seeing it somewhere?

Comment: I'm guessing you're thinking of "centennial", which does not mean "turn of the century", but rather a 100-year anniversary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***"[Fin de siècle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fin_de_si%C3%A8cle)"*** is a French expression used in English to mean "end of the century" not "turn of the century". (Wikipedia)

It's not exact, I know, but related. Might be of help.

Comment: Though it's originally a French noun phrase, as a loan word / lexical borrowing it's become accepted as a fully-fledged adjective too  {[Collins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fin+de+siecle)}:  **fin de siècle**
n
1. (Historical Terms) the end of the 19th century, when traditional social, moral, and artistic values were in transition
adj
2. (Historical Terms) of or relating to the close of the 19th century